# Error: error while updating property 'startpoint' of a view managed by bvlineargradient. Null

Tags: reactjs, react-native, linear-gradients

When i change the sliders value to change the startX/startY value i get this Error: error while updating property 'startpoint' of a view managed by bvlineargradient. Null

```
const [startX, setStartX] = useState(0);
const [startY, setStartY] = useState(0);

<LinearGradient
  start={{x: startX, y: startY}}
  end={{x: 0.5, y: 1.3}}
  locations={[0.4, 0.9]}
  colors={[colorOne, colorTwo]}
  style={{
    height: 200,
    width: '100%',
    borderRadius: 10,
}}></LinearGradient>

<Slider
  thumbTintColor="#fff"
  minimumValue={0}
  maximumValue={1}
  step={0.1}
  value={startX}
  onValueChange={val => setStartX(val)}
 />
```

Comment: You may try changing your import to `import LinearGradient from '../screens/LinearGradientFunction.js'`.

Comment: @kiuQ It's still the same. I can see the colors and all the other props in console.log but it doesnt want to show the colors on screen. I have even set a border to see if the view is showing and it is . but no colors.